# Regular expression matching .xlsx links

Tags: java, regex

I have a html from which i need to extract a link ending with .xlsx

i have a regular expression which can extract all the links

```
\s*(?i)href\s*=\s*("([^"]*")|'[^']*'|([^'">\s]+))
```

can any one help me to modify this regular expression which will get the links only ending with .xlsx

Comment: can you post an example of your String? or your form because i do not understand what you spect because you could use endsWith()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append `\.xlsx` to each three parts which combined by OR operator (`|`) . So, your regex is:

```
\s*(?i)href\s*=\s*("([^"]*\.xlsx")|'[^']*\.xlsx'|([^'">\s]+\.xlsx))
```